# Generate APK for a react-native with nodejs application created using expo

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo, apk, mobile-application

I need to generate APK build for my react-native and NodeJs application created using expo.

I tried creating using `eas build -p android --profile preview`

I have managed to create an APK but when I try to run it in the Android simulator and also in my mobile it's not working. Is there any other way.

`eas.json: { "build": { "preview": { "android": { "buildType": "apk" } }, "preview2": { "android": { "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease" } }, "preview3": { "developmentClient": true }, "production": {} } }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to your `eas.json` file inside your `preview` object,

```json
"distribution": "internal",
```

Before running the command to build, try to run the following

> cd android && ./gradlew clean

after this command, run the following

> eas build --profile preview --platform android

If you encounter the same error, try to debug with `adb`. This will provide more information for you on how and why your application does not work!